# Significance test of counts in two groups in R

Tags: r, frequency, significance

I would like to compare the number of counts (`counts`) of two groups (`A` and `B`) per given time interval in seconds (`interval`) in order to test

a.) if there is a significant difference between the groups in the total number of counts

b.) if there is a significant difference in counts between group 'A' and 'B' per given **time interval**.

I am not even sure which test should I use (e.g. Chi-test, t-test or else) but also how to convert the data frame to execute it in R.

This is my dummy example:

### Variables:

```
group      <-  c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
interval   <-  c("30","60","90","120","30","60","90","120")
counts     <-  c(72,57,38,32,108,46,70,55)
```

### Data frame

```
df <-  data.frame(group,interval,counts)
df
```

As advised in the comments below my post, I played around with the following code from "Repeated Measures Analysis" (see [LINK](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/seminars/repeated-measures-analysis-with-r/)) but I'm pretty sure there is smth wrong with it:

```
   ## Convert variables to factor
  demo1 <- within(df, {
  group <- factor(group)
  time <- factor(interval, levels = c("30", "60", "90","120"))})                                       
  par(cex = .6)

  with(demo1, interaction.plot(time, group, counts,
  ylim = c(0,108), lty= c(1, 12), lwd = 3,
  ylab = "counts", xlab = "time", trace.label = "group"))

  demo1.aov <- aov(counts ~ group * time + Error(counts), data = demo1)
  summary(demo1.aov)
```

Comment: If you group your data by `interval` you will have only two values to compare. Do you really need a test for that comparison? For instance, for _interval = 30_ you will just compare _72_ and _108_

Comment: The idea I had in my mind is a test if there is a significant difference "over time", from 30 sec to 120 sec, in the number of counts produced by these two groups. I'm not an expert, maybe I'm asking a wrong question but from what I've seen on different platforms the binary comparison shouldn't be a problem. Again, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: For some valid statistics it is recommended to have at least three samples per subgroup. Thus your analysis will not work. if there would be more measurments then you could try `library(tidyverse);
df %>% 
  split(.$interval) %>% 
  map(~broom::tidy(wilcox.test(counts ~ group, data=.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "interval")`

Comment: Hi @Jo-Achna, do you mean you want to figure out in time point 30, 60, 90, 120, is there difference in counts between group A and B?

Comment: @Xiwa Yes. Correct

Comment: You mean the order ("over time") matters? If so, you should be interested in [repeated measures analysis](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/seminars/repeated-measures-analysis-with-r/)

Comment: if you got enough data points of groupA and B in each time point in your real world dataset, maybe @ANG 's suggestion can be helpful. sample size matters.

Comment: @ANG: I followed the link provided in the comments on repeated measures analysis and my output is not entirely correct. How can I show you what I see? Shall I include this info in my original post or make a new post below?

Comment: @Jo-Achna Your question in you original post is unclear (do you want an unique test per `interval`? What do you mean by _"over time"_, does order matter?...). Please read and edit your question. Also, Cross Validated is more relevant for such question

Comment: @ANG: I did my best to be more precise in my post. Hope, the current version is more clear now